# Save in two different divs two variables obtained by url

Tags: javascript

Good day,
I have a code that I can not get it out I have a script that gets the variables and data from the url and saves them in a string. Everything works correctly until the moment of extracting each value from the string and then showing it in a `<div id="data1" />` extracting the data from the string with `document.getElementById('data1').innerHTML = valores[index];`.
I enclose the code so that they can verify it the problem arises from `window.onload = function ()`

```
        <script>
            function getGET()
            {
                var loc = document.location.href;
                if(loc.indexOf('?')>0)
                {
                    var getString = loc.split('?')[1];
                    var GET = getString.split('&');
                    var get = {};
                    for(var i = 0, l = GET.length; i < l; i++){
                        var tmp = GET[i].split('=');
                        get[tmp[0]] = unescape(decodeURI(tmp[1]));
                    }
                    return get;
                }
            }
              window.onload = function()
              {
                  var valores=getGET();
                  if(valores)
                  {
                      var data1 = valores['data1'];
                      var data2 = valores['data2'];
                      for(var index in valores)
                      {
                          document.getElementById('data1').innerHTML = valores[index];
                          document.getElementById('data2').innerHTML = valores[index];
                      }
                  }else{

                  }
               }
    </script>
    <div id="data1" />
    <div id="data2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem with the two getElementById lines at the end of the code? Is it because you are trying to get the elements with id's "codigoo" and "email" and not "data1" and "data2"? When tested, this code will display the parameters in the URL.

```
<script>
    function getGET()
    {
        var loc = document.location.href;
        if(loc.indexOf('?')>0)
        {
            var getString = loc.split('?')[1];
            var GET = getString.split('&');
            var get = {};
            for(var i = 0, l = GET.length; i < l; i++){
                var tmp = GET[i].split('=');
                get[tmp[0]] = unescape(decodeURI(tmp[1]));
            }
            return get;
        }
    }
    window.onload = function()
    {
      var valores=getGET();
      if(valores)
      {
          var data1 = valores['data1'];
          var data2 = valores['data2'];
          for(var index in valores)
          {
              document.getElementById('data1').innerHTML = valores[index];
              document.getElementById('data2').innerHTML = valores[index];
          }
      }else{

      }
    }
</script>
<div id="data1" />
<div id="data2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the oversight, the two `getElementById` are with data1 and data2 and the problem is in these same ones where I just take the last value I sent and shows them in the two divs.

If the url is www.example.com/index.php?data1=value1&data2=value2
But the two divs (data1 and data2) shows only the data2
div(data1)= value2
div(data2)= value2